# How to move element behind parent with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have question about css positioning. Is it possible to move element behind parent to the left/right window's border? For example parent has `max-width 1220px` and for bigger window's sizes I don't understand how to move element to the left border.

Very important: it must be responsive! In case if i set margin-left: -200px, it is not responsive

Image:
[image]

Here is some code:

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.element {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.left {
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="left">This element has to be on the left side of window</div>
    <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the smallest container to view:

```
.left {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Test script:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="left">This element has to be on the left side of window</div>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the page must be responsive. Solution margin-left: -200px not working when window is resized

Comment: now I understand, you have to prepare the media queries

Comment: do you want the yellow div on the full left?

Comment: No, I want the yellow to be sticky to the left side of window, but with saving element's height